# can't set height of the div in %

Tags: html, css

So I have next structure:

```css
body{ 
 margin:0px;
 background-color:#f2f0f2;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.container {
 display: inline-block;
    height:330%;
}
/* ============================================================
   Parallax
============================================================ */

 div.module.content {
 background-color:#f2f0f2;
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 vertical-align: middle;
    height:330%;
}
 div.module.parallax {
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .5);
 vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
 background-image: url(../img/overlay-pattern.png);
 background-repeat: repeat;
    height:330%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="module parallax">
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="module content">
  <div class="container">
   <p>
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="module parallax">
   <div class="container">
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="module content">
   <div class="container">
  <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="module parallax">
   <div class="container">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="module content">
   <div class="container">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And I'm trying to set height of the divs in % and it must be working, but it doesnt, it only accepts px or vw, but it doesn't accept value in %.

Why so? How can I fix it?

I feel it's a very simple reason, but I don't see it.

Comment: How about adding `html{height:100%}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not set height for the parent element, it can't calculate the % of what element?

Setting `html { height: 100%; }` gives the browser an idea of the height of the parent element.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f2f0f2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 330%;
}
/* ============================================================
       Parallax
    ============================================================ */

div.module.content {
  background-color: #f2f0f2;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 330%;
}
div.module.parallax {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .5);
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../img/overlay-pattern.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 330%;
}
```

```html
<div class="module parallax">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="module parallax">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="module parallax">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="module content">
  <div class="container">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But html is the parent of body :) HTML will be limited to certain height when unspecified, so body inside it will be of limited height as well.